# ValueAccessing data frames with multiple condition applied on columns giving error. Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am accessing dataframes columns based on conditions applied on two columns
I had the following code

```
def data1(q,t,sub):
    lit=[]
    a=df['teacher']==t & df['subject']==sub
    lit = df[q].where(df['teacher'].values == t) and (df['subject'].values == sub).dropna()

lit = df[q].where(a).dropna()
return lit
```

but I am getting this error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you can clean up the question, especially the code, it will make it a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where the error message isn't very helpful. You want to use `&` rather than `and` in your `where`:

```
df[q].where((df['teacher'].values == t) & (df['subject'].values == sub))
```